# Remove Doubleqoutes and insert a character

Tags: vb.net

I have the two paragraphs below in a multiline textbox and I want to:

1. Replace the numbers 1 and 2 with Q1 and Q2, and
2. Remove all the quotes.

> 1. According to Forbes & Hawranik (found in Kulig & Williams, 2012), which of the following is a unique characteristic of rural residents
>      with dementia?
>
>    A.    They are less likely to have an adult child to assist them with care.   B.  They experience a delay in dementia diagnosis.  C.  There is
>      a greater reluctance in accepting specialized care.   D.  They tend to
>      have a later onset of dementia than their urban counterparts.
> 2. A nurse speaks at a staff development in-service. Which statement by a nurse participant shows the need for education?
>
> A.    “I know that the consequences of discrimination are still present
>   and they're linked to health disparities.” B. “I'm sure the percentage
>   of client-care hours that we spend working with minority clients is
>   bound to increase.” C.    “Some may erroneously assume that there are few
>   health disparities because Canada has a universal health care system.”
>   D.    “It's inaccurate to link the prevalence of particular diseases with
>   particular minority groups.”

I have tried this code but it is not working:

```
For i = 0 To Val(textcon.Lines.Count) - 1

  If textcon.Lines(i).Contains(Chr(34)) Then
    MyStringBuilder.Replace(Chr(34), "#")
  End If
next
```

Comment: would    outputString = inputString.Replace("1.", "Q1").Replace("2.","Q2").Replace(Chr(34), "")    work?

Comment: tnx uqji it is working on replacing 1.and 2. with q1 and q2 but it cannot remove the doubleqoutes any suggestions

Comment: I just notice that in your text the quote mark are not exactly the usual ones we type out. They could be some special symbols in UTF-8. In that case, just copy the symbol as the input parameter in the Replace function. i.e. Replace("“", "")

Comment: also you probably need to do the same for the closing quote mark.

Comment: I see that is why it is not removing them, but how about if I want to remove those special quotations tried what you have suggested but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this(**For Simple Double Quotes**):

```
For i = 0 To Val(TextBox1.Lines.Count) - 1
       If TextBox1.Lines(i).Contains(Chr(34)) Then
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(Chr(34), "")
       End If
Next
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("1.", "Q1 ")
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("2.", "Q2 ")
```

Try this(**For Curly Double Quotes**):

```
For i = 0 To Val(TextBox1.Lines.Count) - 1            
     TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(Chr(148), "")
     TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(Chr(147), "")
Next
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("1.", "Q1 ")
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("2.", "Q2 ")
```

**There are different types of Double Quotation marks, you can refereed the character code from [here](http://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html)**

Try with this content:(I've change the Curly Quotes to Straight Quotes)

```
1. According to Forbes & Hawranik (found in Kulig & Williams, 2012), which of the following is a unique characteristic of rural residents with dementia?
    A. They are less likely to have an adult child to assist them with care. B. They experience a delay in dementia diagnosis. C. There is a greater reluctance in accepting specialized care. D. They tend to have a later onset of dementia than their urban counterparts.

2. A nurse speaks at a staff development in-service. Which statement by a nurse participant shows the need for education?

A. "I know that the consequences of discrimination are still present and they're linked to health disparities." B. "I'm sure the percentage of client-care hours that we spend working with minority clients is bound to increase." C. "Some may erroneously assume that there are few health disparities because Canada has a universal health care system." D. "It's inaccurate to link the prevalence of particular diseases with particular minority groups."
```

Comment: i have tried your code jay but the only thing that was change is 2. with q2 and the doube qoutations has not been remove

Comment: Make sure that if you are copying the content from the website or any other place, the double quotes are valid, because I've copy your content from your question but the double quotes are different from system double quotes hence the compiler could not recognize the quotes and they are remain as it is, So I've put the valid double quotes and it works well on my system.

Comment: Now try again with this content, copy it to your text box and test

Comment: Nice I have missed that, they are not normal quotations, but how about if I want to remove those kind of special quotations is there a equivalent to vb.net  i have try this format .replace("“”", "") but it is not working

Comment: MyStringBuilder.Replace(ans, "Q" & y).Replace(Chr(147), """").Replace(Chr(148), """") i have used it in my code and it works--- awesome..

Comment: remove or replace with the correct double quotations and it is working---nice